# How I can use XML attributes to specify another XML name?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
   <id>19</id>
   <name>Name is here</name>
   <note>leader-it test user</note>
   <list name="products">
      <elem>
         <id>2537</id>
         <name>Product #2537</name>
         <status>Deleted</status>
         <cost>1.00</cost>
      </elem>
      <elem>
         <id>2541</id>
         <name>Product #2541</name>
         <status>Active</status>
         <cost>1.00</cost>
      </elem>
   </list>
   <list name="balance">
      <elem>
         <id>19</id>
         <project>Project 15</project>
         <balance>108046.1716</balance>
      </elem>
   </list>
   <label />
   <country>182</country>
</doc>
```

I'm trying to deserialize it

```
var account = XmlHelper.ParseXml<Account>(xml_string);

public static class XmlHelper
{
    public class NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader : XmlTextReader
    {
         public NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }
         public override string NamespaceURI
        {
            get { return String.Empty; }
        }
    }

    public static T ParseXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        try
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                using (var xmlTextReader = new NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader(reader))
                {
                    return (T)(serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

using these classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "doc")]
public class Account
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("list")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "elem", Type = typeof(ProductListElement), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<ProductListElement> Products { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("list")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "elem", Type = typeof(BalanceListElement), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<BalanceListElement> Balance { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProductListElement
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("cost")]
    public string Cost { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class BalanceListElement
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int BalanceId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("project")]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("balance")]
    public string Balance { get; set; }
}
```

I've got this error:

> The XML element 'list' from namespace '' is already present in the
>   current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or
>   namespace for the element.

How I can use XML attributes to specify another XML name?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear, I could not copy of your code in a  console app .net framework. I have some error. NamespaceIgnorantXmlTextReader class or about T keyword. Can you check your information.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: thanks for updating. I try something but I couldn't too.

Comment: It is impossible to do only with the help of xml attributes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have two properties in the class with the tag 'elem'.  There is no need to use arrays in this case.  See class below :

```
   [XmlRoot(ElementName = "doc")]
    public class Account
    {
        [XmlElement("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("note")]
        public string Note { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "list")]
        public List<BalanceListElement> Balance { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("country")]
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The error is "The XML element 'list' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope." In your example, the "list" element occurs only once, so there will be no error. This doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Look at your code again.  You have this statement twice :  [XmlArray("list")]

Comment: This is the problem. These  [XmlArray("list")] elements need to be splitted in two properties. How?

Comment: Have BalanceListElement and ProductListElement inherit the same base class.  So you would have public List<BaseListElement> Products

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try.

Comment: Yes, it works. This isn't the answer to the question, but it solved the problem. Thanks.